# MessageBox.Show Not Blocking Thread

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, csla

I'm doing maintenance on a website based on Silverlight using the MVVM pattern and built on the CSLA framework for its business logic.  A strange issue has recently popped up where I  have to hit save multiple times before the save dialogue shows up on screen.  After a bit of investigating, I have found that a MessageBox OK / Cancel dialogue, which should block the thread until OK or Cancel is clicked, is letting the thread step through it without anything showing up on the screen at all.  Here is the relevant method in the viewmodel's base class:

```
    private void SavingProcess(object sender, ExecuteEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSavedProcessCancelled = true;
        MessageBoxResult result;

        if (IgnoreSaveMessageBox) 
            result = MessageBoxResult.OK;
        else
            result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to save the data?", "Data Changes", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsSavedProcessCancelled = false;
            base.Save(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

IgnoreSaveMessageBox is false and the execution of the code goes to the else statement correctly.  When I step through it, it goes through the MessageBox.Show() line like it would any other.  Even stranger, result actually has a value of 'None' afterwards instead of being null as I expected.

I decided to try wrapping the first if / else statement in a while loop to see what would happen (I realize this is a really gnarly thing to do and wouldn't have accepted it as a solution even if it had worked):

```
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBoxResult.None;

        while (result != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            if (IgnoreSaveMessageBox)
                result = MessageBoxResult.OK;
            else
                result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to save the data?", "Data Changes", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        }
```

This will eventually cause the dialogue to show up, but it takes eight or nine iterations through the loop.  This also only happens when I am trying to save a specific grid full of list items and the list has to be 30+ items large; smaller lists do not have this issue.

I've worked around this by setting 'IgnoreSaveMessageBox' to true when saving in this particular instance, but I'm hoping someone out there can put me on the path to fixing this properly.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: What thread are you running on?

Comment: Can you verify that you're using the correct MessageBox class? It should be System.Windows.MessageBox from System.Windows.dll.

Comment: @Tanis83 I just checked and that is indeed the class and dll that is being used.

Comment: What is invoking the SavingProcess method?  my guess is that method is executing on a background thread.  I believe too that Silverlight never lets the ui thread get blocked.